# Wordpress: get post id where slug name is LIKE something

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Please help me with my custom function `get_post_by_slug`, which tries to query the database and get post id where slug is `LIKE` `something%` from a specific category (`id=5`). It worked until WP 3.5, but it is broken now, I think there could be a problem with the cache. I added `$wpdb->prepare` for WP 3.5 but it didn't really fix the problem.

```
function get_post_by_slug($post_slug) {
  global $wpdb;
  $post = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id WHERE post_name LIKE '%s%' AND term_taxonomy_id=5 LIMIT 1", $post_slug));
  return $post;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`prepare` is like `sprintf` so it uses the `%` you use for the `LIKE` you can do it like this.
Also you should remove the `''` around the `%s` if you using prepare, prepare will quote for you. Think the next example will work for you.

```
function get_post_by_slug($post_slug) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_slug = '%' . $post_slug . '%';
    $post = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id WHERE post_name LIKE %s AND term_taxonomy_id=5 LIMIT 1", $post_slug));
    return $post;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on $wpdb->prepare(), however, the query still doesn't return posts...

Comment: When I run this query: `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id WHERE post_name LIKE '%hello-world%' AND term_taxonomy_id=2 LIMIT 1` it worked, so maybe you can test it manually to see what is wrong.

Comment: Actually, a strange thing happens. The function always returns the same result... Could there be a cache that I don't know about? Is WP caching such things?

Comment: It shouldn't have caching in database, have you experimented in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It's not caching different query's. It's more likely that your post_slug is the same, have you checked that?

Answer (score -2):

Simplest solution to get post id by slug, is this:

```
$your_desired_title = "yourtitle";

global $wpdb;
$id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = $your_desired_title ");
echo $id;
```